# How do && and || work constructing queries in NEST?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

According to http://nest.azurewebsites.net/concepts/writing-queries.html, the && and || operators can be used to combine two queries using the NEST library to communicate with Elastic Search.

I have the following query set up:

```
var ssnQuery = Query<NameOnRecordDTO>.Match(
                q => q.OnField(f => f.SocialSecurityNumber).QueryString(nameOnRecord.SocialSecurityNumber).Fuzziness(0)
            );
```

which is then combined with a Bool query as shown below:

```
var result = client.Search<NameOnRecordDTO>(
     body => body.Query(
          query => query.Bool(
              bq => bq.Should(
                  q => q.Match(
                     p => p.OnField(f => f.Name.First)
                         .QueryString(nameOnRecord.Name.First).Fuzziness(fuzziness)
                  ),
                  q => q.Match(p => p.OnField(f => f.Name.Last)
                         .QueryString(nameOnRecord.Name.Last).Fuzziness(fuzziness)
                  )
              ).MinimumNumberShouldMatch(2)
          ) || ssnQuery
     )
);
```

What I think this query means is that if the `SocialSecurityNumber` matches, or both the `Name.First` and `Name.Last` fields match, then the record should be included in the results.

When I execute this query with the follow data for the nameOnRecord object used in the calls to QueryString:

```
"socialSecurityNumber":"123456789",
    "name" : {
      "first":"ryan",          
    }
```

the results are the person with SSN `123456789`, along with anyone with first name `ryan`.

If I remove the `|| ssnQuery` from the query above, I get everyone whose first name is 'ryan'.

With the `|| ssnQuery` in place and the following query:

```
{
    "socialSecurityNumber":"123456789",
    "name" : {
      "first":"ryan",
      "last": "smith"
    }        
}
```

I appear to get the person with SSN 123456789 along with people whose first name is 'ryan' or last name is 'smith'.

So it does not appear that adding `|| ssnQuery` is having the effect that I expected, and I don't know why.

Here is the definition of the index on object in question:

```
"nameonrecord" : {
    "properties": {      
        "name": {
            "properties": {
                "name.first": {
                    "type": "string"
                 },
                 "name.last": {
                    "type": "string"
                 }
             }   
        },
        "address" : {
            "properties": {
                "address.address1": {
                    "type": "string",
                     "index_analyzer": "address",
                     "search_analyzer": "address"
                 },
                "address.address2": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "address"
                 },
                 "address.city" : {
                    "type": "string", 
                    "analyzer": "standard"
                 },
                 "address.state" : {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "standard"
                 },
                 "address.zip" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "analyzer": "standard"
                 }
            }   
        },                
        "otherName": {
           "type": "string"
        },
        "socialSecurityNumber" : {
           "type": "string"   
        },
        "contactInfo" : {
           "properties": {
                "contactInfo.phone": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "contactInfo.email": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }                
     }   
}
```

I don't think the definition of the `address` analyzer is important, since the address fields are not being used in the query, but can include it if someone wants to see it.

Comment: This is a bug and it will be fixed in the next release, will post an answer with the details later.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This was in fact a bug in NEST

A precursor to how NEST helps translate boolean queries:

NEST allows you to use operator overloading to create verbose bool queries/filters easily i.e:

`term && term`  will result in:

```
bool
    must
        term
        term
```

A naive implementation of this would rewrite

`term && term && term` to

```
bool
    must
        term
        bool
            must
                term
                term
```

As you can image this becomes unwieldy quite fast the more complex a query becomes NEST can spot these and join them together to become

```
bool
    must 
        term
        term
        term
```

Likewise `term && term && term && !term` simply becomes:

```
bool
    must 
        term
        term
        term
    must_not
        term
```

now if in the previous example you pass in a booleanquery directly like so

`bool(must=term, term, term) && !term`

it would still generate the same query. NEST will also do the same with `should`'s when it sees that the boolean descriptors in play ONLY consist of `should clauses`. This is because the boolquery does not quite follow the same boolean logic you expect from a programming language.

To summarize the latter:

`term || term || term`

becomes

```
bool
    should
        term
        term
        term
```

but

`term1 && (term2 || term3 || term4)` will NOT become

```
bool
    must 
        term1
    should
        term2
        term3
        term4
```

This is because as soon as a boolean query has a must clause the should start acting as a boosting factor. So in the previous you could get back results that ONLY contain `term1` this is clearly not what you want in the strict boolean sense of the input.

NEST therefor rewrites this query to

```
bool 
    must 
        term1
        bool
            should
                term2
                term3
                term4
```

Now where the bug came into play was that your situation you have this

`bool(should=term1, term2, minimum_should_match=2) || term3` NEST identified both sides of the OR operation only contains should clauses and it would join them together which would give a different meaning to the `minimum_should_match` parameter of the first boolean query.

I just pushed a fix for this and this will be fixed in the next release `0.11.8.0`

Thanks for catching this one!

Comment: Hi Martjin, thanks for this explanation. I guess this is something related to my problem. Could you please kindly check my question here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38894540/how-to-combine-multi-match-queries